# WP woocommerce change "Proceed to checkout" buttons URL

Tags: wordpress, button, woocommerce

I want to change to URL of the "Proceed to checkout" button. I wanna do this to to check if there's a need for my product, so my customers shouldn't be able to really buy it. Therefore I want to direct them not to the checkout but to a customized page of mine.

Thanks a lot.

Josh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be available at below path

`wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/proceed-to-checkout-button.php`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked out perfektly.

Comment: @J0shis it's not a good practice to change core files. after updating woocommerce you willlose the modification !

Answer (score 3):

the best way is the woocommerce hooks

Try to use this code (put it in your functions.php theme file).

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'my_change_checkout_url', 30 );

function my_change_checkout_url( $url ) {
   $url = "your checkout url ";
   return $url;
}
```

You can customize it by adding some conditions to change the checkout url

for example:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'my_change_checkout_url', 30 );
function my_change_checkout_url( $url ) {
    $allowed_countries = array('FR');
    $customer_country = WC()->customer->get_default_country();
    if( !in_array( $customer_country , $allowed_countries ) ) {
        $url = wc_get_page_permalink( 'other-checkout' );
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change Proceed To Checkout Text In WooCommerce
* Change Proceed To Checkout Text in WooCommerce
* Place this in your Functions.php file
This is the new method, for version 2.3.8 of WooCommerce and forward.

```
<?php
function woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout() {
       $checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
       ?>
       <a href="<?php echo $checkout_url; ?>" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward"><?php _e( 'Check On Out', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
       <?php
     }
```